# CCSprite x and y comparison

Tags: collision-detection, ios, cocos2d-iphone, objective-c, ccsprite

I have 2 CCSprites and I want to tell if their x and y are equal I tried this:

```
if(sam.position.x == tom.position.x && sam.position.y == tom.position.y){
NSLog(@"Hooray!");
}
```

Although I do not think this is the right way to do this. Could anyone help me?

Thanks.

**ALSO** The CCSprites are named sam and tom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That works, but might cause problems because of floats. It would be better to factor in some margin of error.. maybe half a screen-point... that would then look like this

```
if(fabsf(sam.position.x - tom.position.x) < 0.5f && fabsf(sam.position.y - tom.position.y) < 0.5f)
```

Of course you can change the "threshold/accuracy" by increasing or decreasing the `0.5f` value.